# Rotating an equilateral triangle at its center

Tags: kotlin, graphics, rotation

I am writing a Kotlin function of the Java `Graphics` class which will fill in an equilateral triangle with its center at the given coordinates. I am now attempting to add the functionality to rotate the triangle give a `theta` in degrees.

Reading into point rotation, I found the equations `x′ = xcosθ − ysinθ` and `y′ = ycosθ + xsinθ` which in addition to translating `x` and `y` to the origin before the rotation and then translating the result back, seems to be the solution I'm looking for.

However, upon implementation, it appears that the triangle is almost rotating in simulated 3D space.

**My Code**

```
fun Graphics.fillTriangle(x: Int, y: Int, sideLength: Int, theta: Int = 0) {
    var xCords = arrayOf(x - (sideLength / 2),
                         x + (sideLength / 2),
                         x)

    var yCords = arrayOf((y + (sideLength / (2 * sqrt(3.0)))).toInt(),
                         (y + (sideLength / (2 * sqrt(3.0)))).toInt(),
                         (y - (sideLength / sqrt(3.0))).toInt())

    if(theta != 0) {
        for(i in 0..2) {
            xCords[i] = ((xCords[i]-x) * cos(toRadians(theta)) - (yCords[i]-y) * sin(toRadians(theta))).toInt() + x
            yCords[i] = ((yCords[i]-y) * cos(toRadians(theta)) + (xCords[i]-x) * sin(toRadians(theta))).toInt() + y
        }
    }

    fillPolygon(xCords.toIntArray(), yCords.toIntArray(), 3)
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't check your math, but I'd suggest a simpler approach. For each point, calculate where it would be for a triangle centered at the origin, and then add the offset. An equilateral triangle is just three points on a circle, 120 degrees apart, so the math is just `(x, y) = (r*cos(theta), r*sin(theta))`.

```
fun Graphics.fillTriangle(x: Int, y: Int, sideLength: Int, theta: Int = 0) {
    val radius = sideLength / sqrt(3.0)
    val angles = (0..2).map { it * (toRadians(theta) + toRadians(120)) }
    val xCoords = angles.map { (radius * cos(it) + x).roundToInt() }.toIntArray()
    val yCoords = angles.map { (radius * sin(it) + y).roundToInt() }.toIntArray()
    fillPolygon(xCoords, yCoords, 3)
}
```

Comment: I figured it out using my approach, but thanks for the simplification; that is much more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was modifying the coordinate in the `xCord` array which was then utilized to calculate the new coordinate in the `yCord` array.

**My New Code**

```
var newX = (((xCords[i]-x) * cos(toRadians(theta)) - (yCords[i]-y)*sin(toRadians(theta)))+ x).toInt()
var newY = (((yCords[i]-y) * cos(toRadians(theta)) + (xCords[i]-x) * sin(toRadians(theta))) + y).toInt()

xCords[i] = newX
yCords[i] = newY
```